# How to get the data from user_fields?

Tags: tweepy

I'm struggeling with getting the username from the user who created the tweet.
Already added the expansion "user_fields" (this works), but now I have problems getting the data out of it (everything else "tweet-fields" related works).

I already tried tweet.username and tweet.user_name .. nothing works and the documentation also does not help much. Anyone has an Idea how to tackle the problem?

Thanks in advance!

```
for ids in liste:
    berlintweets = tweepy.Paginator(client.get_users_tweets,
                                    id=ids,
                                    exclude=["replies", "retweets"],
                                    end_time=current_time,
                                    start_time=first_day_of_month,
                                    tweet_fields=["created_at", "author_id", "public_metrics"],
                                    user_fields=["name", "username"],
                                    max_results=100).flatten(limit=500)
    for tweet in berlintweets:
        tweet_id_list.append(tweet.id)
        tweet_created_at.append(tweet.created_at)
        tweet_text_list.append(tweet)
        tweet_user_id.append(tweet.author_id)
        tweet_user_name.append(tweet?????)
```

Answer (score 1):

The `User` objects are in the `response.includes`, not in the `response.data`.

Basically, you have to ask for the `author_id` expansion in your request if you want the `User` objects to be included in the response, then you get the `author_id` field in each tweet in the `responses.data`, and you can search for the `User` with this `id` in the `response.includes`.

Here is an example adapted from the Tweepy documentation:

```py
# You can specify expansions to retrieve additional objects that relate to the
# returned results
response = client.search_recent_tweets(
    "Tweepy", expansions=["author_id"]
)

# Tweets ARE the response.data and Users are IN the response.includes
tweets = response.data
users = response.includes["users"]

# The IDs that represent the expanded objects are included directly in the
# returned data objects
for tweet in tweets:
    print(tweet.author_id)

# An efficient way of matching expanded objects to each data object is to
# create a dictionary of each type of expanded object, with IDs as keys
users = {user["id"]: user for user in users}
for tweet in tweets:
    print(tweet.id, users[tweet.author_id].username)
```

You can read more about expansions [here](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/expansions) (Twitter documentation).

Finally, please note that, if you use pagination, you can't use the `flatten` method because there is no way to access the `response.includes` when doing so.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But why can't I use "user_fields" ? According to tweepy thats official way to do it (https://docs.tweepy.org/en/stable/client.html#tweepy.Client.get_users_tweets)

Comment: I mean worst case i need to look up the usernames with the author_id (which I'm already getting via Twitter_fields) seperatly and not within the nested For-Loop, but that still would not explain why i can access data from the one kind of field and not from the other one.

Comment: @MaxMastermann `user_fields` is used to specify the fields that will be set in the `User` objects in the `response.includes`, nothing more.

Comment: So same as "tweet_fields". This is what i get. But why can get the Tweet objects in the response.includes without any problems (although I'm using pagination and flatten)

Comment: @MaxMastermann No. The requested tweets' fields are located in the `response.data` and the requested users' fields are located in the `response.includes` (to avoid redundancy). And the `flatten` method iterate only through the `response.data` so it is unsuitable for your use-case. You should read again the code sample that I gave you and make some testings with it.